# How to separate two digits in single column into two columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose we have a data frame as so:

```
col_1
0 1
2 3
4 5
```

How do I separate the two numbers into two columns? i.e. to get:

```
col_1 col_2
0     1
2     3
4     5
```

Insight appreciated!

Comment: You can try `data.table::tstrsplit(df$col_1,"\\s+")`.

Comment: `tidyr::separate(df, col_1, c('col1', 'col2'))`